# What may "that last one" mean when related to men's sexual activity?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

**Context:**

A married couple spying on their teenage son via a special computer program, start finding out the details of his interest in sex.

Here's an extract from their dialogue that puzzled me:

> “Talk to him,” she said.
>
> “I have,” Mike said. “I’ve explained the birds-n-bees. I’ve explained
>   that sex is best when blended with love. I’ve tried to teach him to
>   respect women, not objectify them.”
>
> “That last one,” Tia said. “He’s not getting that last one.”
>
> “No male teenager gets that last one. Hell, I’m not even sure any male
>   adult gets that one.”

(Harlan Coben,"Hold Tight", chapter 5)

What has puzzled me is *"that last one"* phrase which doesn't seem to be used in the context of actual cases of sexual intercourse -- all that was said before is that their son watches online porn.

So what *"that last one"* means in the context is unclear to me. Could anyone explain what it stands for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"That last one" has nothing to do with sexual intercourse, it refers to the last thing mentioned - "not objectify them" in this case.

Comment: So, "that last _one_" stands for _the point_ "not to objectify women", which, according to the man-speaker, barely any man gets. Got it, thanks.

Comment: @Rompey: "that last one" = that last item on the list of things you say you have discussed with him.